# Importing test result files on .tap format into sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

We are testing SonarQube to see if it's usage would be good for us. Our project has a test suite which outputs test results to .tap files.  Would it be possible to get them integrated into SonarQube so that it shows how many tests were performed and how many failed? Is there some plugin available that I couldn't find or would that require writing my own? Any pointers for where to start looking would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are generated using the [Test Anything Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol), I don't think an import plugin exists for SonarQube.

If you wish to roll your own, you can have an overview of what is required on the [Plugin Development documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Started). The classes from the `org.sonar.api.test` package will be your entry point for the injection of test related data.

For the report parsing part, you can have a look at the [Tap4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tap4j/) library.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought as I couldn't find one. Any idea how much work would it require to develop one from scratch? Also do you know if there are some other alternatives, e.g. in what formats would SonarQube be able to import results of unit tests so if we just converted them into some other format for SQ.

Comment: With good knowledge of the API, I think it would probably take something like 2 weeks for an initial working version, depending on the analyzed languages. As of today, each language plugin uses its own format, but there is an ongoing discussion about defining/using a common, cross-technology test report format.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, a SonarQube plugin for TAP has been created:
https://github.com/dbac2002/sonar-tap-parser